# Cannot log out of iOS Swift app when connecting to Rails API using Doorkeeper & Devise

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

Ok - after 48 hours I give up.  I have my Rails 3.2 app setup with Doorkeeper and Devise.  The doorkeeper.rb initializer is pretty straight forward:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do 
  current_account || warden.authenticate!(:scope => :account)
end
```

and I am using the awesome p2_oauth POD in an iOS Swift app for OAuth2 connecting.  Here's the problem/oddity:

When I go to login and the OAuth2 dance begins, p2 uses iOS's embedded web view to hit my Rails API.  Since there is no current_account, it redirects appropriately to login.  Great.

HOWEVER - I CANNOT LOG OUT.

I've tried everything:

- warden.logout
- signout
- session.delete("warden.user.account.key")
- clearing cookies in the Rails App when the logout route is called
- clearing the sessions  in the Rails App when the logout route is called
- etc

Regardless of what I do, when I go to login again the Rails app is RETAINING the current_account!?  I inspected the session and, sure enough, there is a warden.user.account.key still in the session!  It's infuriating.

If I stop and restart the iOS app in the simulator, all is well again until I login/logout.  So clearly it's like there is some session that iOS is maintaining and not clearing that the Rails app is reading.  Im also making sure that my request has a no cache policy:

```
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.HTTPMethod = "DELETE"

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = nil
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:
```

I honestly cant believe that no one else has come across this.  How am I suppose to log out with this setup?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? I'm also having a similar issue.

Comment: I ended up using password grant flow instead of the web view to avoid the whole cookie session situation

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to follow up on your comment.

Just to recap what problem I had that brought me to your question:
User can log in fine but couldn't properly log out. Once they clicked log in again, it would automatically log in without asking for password again.

As you said, using the password grant flow would indeed avoid the cookie session. For me, I had to use a webview of some sorts in my iOS app. So I had to stick with the **authorization_code** grant.

I spent an entire week trying to figure out what was going on with **doorkeeper**+**devise** (all my links are purple...), and I finally found a solution that works for me. I'm not sure it's the proper way to do it though because I'm not familiar with ruby on rails at all. I'll have to go through the code again later.

Basically, what to do is add this to **config/routes.rb** where you say user_doorkeeper

```
use_doorkeeper do
    controllers applications: 'doorkeeper', authorizations: 'authorizations'
end
```

Then add an authorizations controller here **app/controllers/authorizations_controller.rb**

```
class AuthorizationsController < Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController
  def new
    super
    env['warden'].logout
  end
end
```

This forces the user to logout on log in. For the code, I think what it's doing is overriding/adding code to the original AuthorizationsController in Doorkeeper.

I found this solution on what looks like someone's blog, thank you good sir! This will do for now.
http://www.kluks.de/blog/posts/14-rails-4-single-sign-out-of-all-applications-with-doorkeeper.

------------ Edit ------------

For reference, for the provider side, I had been following this [guide](http://dev.mikamai.com/post/110722727899/oauth2-on-rails), while adding stuff I needed. I wouldn't recommend following her clientside tutorial though. That didn't work out for me at all.

**doorkeeper.rb**

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
use_refresh_token
force_ssl_in_redirect_uri false

#for authorization_code grant
resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || begin
        session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
        redirect_to new_user_session_url
    end
end

end
```

Comment: I actually tried that approach as well as trying it on the create method.  For whatever reason that did not work either.  Would you mind posting your devise.rb and doorkeeper.rb?  Maybe I had the wrong config.

Comment: My devise.rb is the default given.
I'll post the doorkeeper.rb.
When you said you tried it on the create method, do you mean you placed env['warden'].logout in sessions_controller.rb? 
I tried to use env['warden'].logout in multiple places, but it only worked for me in the authorizations_controller.rb override.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, same setup on the backend, but we were able to resolve by clearing the cookies on the iOS app.

`[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] removeCookiesSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]];`

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel's answer worked only partially for me. The problem with it was, that the user is signed out directly after calling AuthorizationsController#new, so the subsequent AuthorizationsController#create request, which is required when the user authorizes the app for the first time, does not work.

In order to get the Authorization flow to work correctly, I needed to only sign out the user after the create action, or after the authorize#new if there is no need to authorize the app.

```
class AuthorizationsController < Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController

  def create
    redirect_or_render authorize_response
    # Sign out the user user clicked "Authorize" in the Authorize application page
    warden.logout
  end

  private

  def render_success
    if skip_authorization? || matching_token?
      redirect_or_render authorize_response
      # sign out directly if there is no need for authorizing the app
      warden.logout
    elsif Doorkeeper.configuration.api_only
      render json: pre_auth
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Be aware that this case was used with a Mobile App as client and will not work if the intention is to have SSO for multiple apps.

I use doorkeeper 5.1 and devise 4.7, so it may look a little different for other versions.